# How do you programmatically exit a node.js/express route on an event?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I want to be able to exit execution of a post route when an event is sent from the client-side. I'm using socket.io but I'm not sure it can do what I want. I am using the `uploads` route to process a file, but if the user deletes the file, I want the `app.post` execution to end, similar to either a `res.end()` or `return` statement.

My app in the front-end receives a file from the user and immediately is sent to the post route for processing. If the user deletes the file and uploads a new one, the previous post route is still going. I want to make sure the previous one was terminated, cancelled, etc.

I'm currently using socket.io to communicate front-end to back-end.

How can I achieve this?

```
app.post('/uploads', async (req, res) => {
    // async func1

    // async func2
    // if we receive an event from the front end while processing here, how can I exit the post route?

    // async func3
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `UUID` for each request you make and return it to the `front-end`. The request will be resolved with the `202 ACCEPTED` status code meaning the request was accepted and being handled but the HTTP request will be resolved.

Now you can implement a `resourceManagerServeic` that will allow APIs (`http` or `ws`) to change the state of a resource (like canceling it).

```
app.post('/uploads', async (req, res) => {
    const resourceUuid = resourceManagerServeic.createResource();
    res.status(202); // ACCEPTED
    res.send({ uuid: resourceUuid });


    // start besnise logic
    await function1();
    if(resourceManagerServeic.isCanceled(resourceUuid)) {
      // cleanup
      return; // stop request handling
    }

    await function2();
    if(resourceManagerServeic.isCanceled(resourceUuid)) {
      // cleanup
      return; // stop request handling
    }

    await function3();
    if(resourceManagerServeic.isCanceled(resourceUuid)) {
      // cleanup
      return; // stop request handling
    }
});

app.del('/uploads/:resourceUuid', async (req, res) => {
  resourceManagerServeic.cancle(req.params.resourceUuid);
  res.end() // handle response
});
```

Comment: What resource manager service are you referring to?

Comment: You will need to implement it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your are using Express. Take a look at [express-async-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler.)

You can invoke it

```
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')

app.post('/upload', asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
    await firstfunc()
    await secondfunc()
}))
```

Comment: You haven't shared how to exit the post route on an event.

Comment: My whole post route contains a ```return res.end()``` after. The async functions before are simply for processing the file to other apis, etc. In the meantime the user can delete the file on the front-end. When that happens, I want to essentially call a res.end() from the front-end.